# Populate datablock2 on button click from datablock1 in oracle forms

Tags: search, triggers, oracle10g, oracleforms

I am new to oracle forms.Here is my question.I have 2 datablocks and 1 control block.I have 3 txtboxes in datablock1,a search button in control block and a tabular form in data block2.


Now,If I enter something in the textboxes present in datablock1 and click on search button,It should populate the tabular form in datablock2 based on the search results.

If the text boxes are null and if I click on search button,It should populate the tabular form  with all the details.

Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should created a where clause with the field entered in the when-button-pressed trigger.
Then you need to use set_block_property to set the one time where clause of the block, or if you want to use the same query when the user fires a query in the tabular form the default where property of the block.
for example:

```
DECLARE
  v_where VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  v_where:='DEPTNO='||'10'; 
  set_Block_Property('EMP',ONETIME_WHERE,v_where);
  Execute_Query(all_records);
END;
```